# SQL Server Specific term full text search is not working

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, full-text-search

I'm trying to perform an specific term full-text search in SQL Server. It looks like the way to do it is by wrapping the keywords in double quotes, which I'm doing in my app:

```
Query = "\"" + model.SearchString + "\""
```

However, when I perform the query against the database with a term such as "foo bar", it returns every occurrence of "foo" and "bar" inside the database. The expected result is that the database should return only the records that have "foo bar" specifically. This is the query:

```
SELECT o.OpinionDocumentId
FROM CONTAINSTABLE(OpinionDocuments, Html, @query) AS KEY_TBL
LEFT JOIN dbo.OpinionDocuments AS o ON o.OpinionDocumentId = KEY_TBL.[KEY]
WHERE o.Date BETWEEN @from AND @to
```

What could be the reason why this query is not returning the results from an specific set of keywords?

Thanks

Comment: What is the entire query with the model.SearchString.  Also DBA.StackExchange may be a better place for this.

Comment: The query should go like this with model.SearchString:
`SELECT o.OpinionDocumentId FROM CONTAINSTABLE(OpinionDocuments, Html, '"foo bar"') AS KEY_TBL LEFT JOIN dbo.OpinionDocuments AS o ON o.OpinionDocumentId =KEY_TBL.[KEY]
    WHERE o.Date BETWEEN @from AND @to`

Comment: If you run the query without the WHERE clause and use '"foo bar"' instead of the parameter does it work? Your WHERE clause is on columns from the table on the right hand side of a LEFT JOIN, essentially making it an INNER JOIN - is this what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this via Dba.stackexchange: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/89821/sql-server-specific-term-full-text-search-is-not-working

Using NEAR will solve the issue:

```
CONTAINSTABLE(OpinionDocuments, HTML, 'NEAR((Foo, bar), 0, TRUE)') AS KEY_TBL
```

Where 'Foo' and 'Bar' are the keywords, 0 the amount of distance between them, and TRUE specifies that the order is important